# How can I use sidekiq monitoring with a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sidekiq

My routes file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'
require 'sequel'

get '/' do
   # Some stuff
end

get '/sidekiq' do
    run Sidekiq::Web
end
```

Going to `http://localhost:4567/sidekiq`:

```
NoMethodError at /sidekiq
undefined method `run' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x007f670d2123b8>
```

I am using `bundle exec sidekiq -r ./workers/gyf_downloader.rb` to start Sidekiq first and then `bundle exec ruby routes.rb` to start the Sinatra app.

Any suggestions on how I can get this working?

---

I have already fixed the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

undefined method `join' for #<String:0x007fa504414c08>
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26) at localhost:4567
```

by using `gem 'sinatra', git: 'git@github.com:sinatra/sinatra.git'` in my gemfile as per Mike Perham's answer below saying to check out [this Sinatra issue on github](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/951).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code to **`config.ru`**. Firstly define path to your app, then sidekiq. Next you should add the Sidekiq configuration and path map routes.

```
# config.ru
require './app' 
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/web'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_HOST']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT']}" }
end

run Rack::URLMap.new('/' => App, '/sidekiq' => Sidekiq::Web)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Sinatra:

https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/951

Comment: Thanks for the link. I seem to have fixed that issue but am now getting an undefined method error for run within the my routes file. I edited the original question to give more details.

Comment: You mount Sidekiq::Web, you don't run it within a `get`.